# interceptFrom and interceptSendToEndpoint not working

Tags: apache-camel, interceptor

I was trying to intercept from/to specific rabbitmq route something like the following,
interceptFrom(rabbitmq:localhost/someExchangeName?queue="somerRabbitMqQueueName").to("log:hello");

and i'm not getting anything there.

I've tested
intercept().to("log:hello") and i can confirm it's working, can anyone let me know if there's something else that i need to configure to make the intercept from/to works?

We're using Java DSL and Google Guice for dependency injection.
Some of the project setup as follows,

- camel version: 2.18.3 (tried also 2.19.1)
- camel-guice: 2.18.3
- guice-multibindings: 4.1.0
- camel-rabbitmq: 2.18.3
- maven-compiler-plugin: 1.7

Answer (score 0):

This was also asked on the Camel mailing list.

Make sure it can match the actual url, so make sure they are exact the
same if you are not using wildcard (`*`), you can just do

```
 interceptFrom("rabbitmq:localhost/xxx*")
```

Or try with

```
 interceptFrom("rabbitmq:localhost/xxx?queue=foo*")
```

See also the Camel documentation, and about the wildcard pattern (in the bottom of the page): http://camel.apache.org/intercept